# How to Open VBA from New Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I discovered a missing feature in the new outlook that I need, so I thought I would build it in VBA - but could not find a way to open the VBA editor. I tried Alt + F11, and searching through the settings for "developer" or VBA.

Full disclosure, I haven't tried to use VBA from Outlook in the previous version. I have only used it from Excel, so it's possible there's something fundamentally wrong with my approach. That said, Google tells me I should be able to open VBA in Outlook with Alt + F11 - so I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have been able to learn by searching online, "New Outlook" does not have VBA or the other Developer Tools. New Outlook is perhaps best understood as a replacement to Outlook Express, the old personal email client Microsoft published, or the more recent Windows Mail app. It is not a direct successor or replacement to Microsoft Office Outlook.

Comment: Not entirely true. New Outlook is basically the web version of Microsoft Outlook, but in a GUI. Yes, new outlook is lacking many essential tools that the older Outlook has, such as VBA, PST import/export and other stuff. For simple use New outlook will work, for more advanced use, it will not. Note that Outlook Express had more features too. This is definitely not like Outlook Express. Windows Live Mail, later Windows Mail is the replacement for Outlook Express.

Comment: And this is the replacement for Windows Mail, not Office Outlook, which is what I noted. Windows Mail users have been being prompted to migrated to New Outlook for a few months, and I understand the Mail and Calendar apps have an end date for support from Microsoft. New Outlook is "cloud based", which does match with your statement that it is a client version of Webmail, but I do not see how this makes what I've said incorrect.

Comment: No, its the replacement for Office Outlook. In my Office Outlook, there's a slider: new Outlook, that I can set, and it turns my Office Outlook into the New Outlook that lacks many functions. Luckily, you can switch back. Its great to solve a problem quickly though for someone who relies on email.

Comment: No, it is a replacement for Windows Mail and Windows Calendar. The desktop version of Outlook (part of the Office suite) is still very much supported. The slider is to make the new Outlook (Monarch) more visible.

Comment: There is the "New" version of Office Outlook, activated by sliding that switch, and the "New Outlook" which is a replacement for Windows Mail and Calendar which are pretty much retired at this point. I don't know how much the two are similar. VBA isn't super common in Outlook, not nearly so much as it is in Excel, for comparison. I would guess MS is trying to unify these products, but on the one hand OP doesn't indicate which of these their problem is in, and on the other, I'm guessing it might not matter. My own experience with New Outlook is on my personal computer replacing Mail/Cal.